# Regexp: ProFTPD auth-logs

Tags: regex, linux, plesk, proftpd

I've configurated **ProFTPD** to log all authentifications on a Plesk powered server. This setting is not set by default since Plesk 10 (whyever...). I want to configure fail2ban, to detect unsuccessful login-attempts for Brute Force prevention.

`/etc/proftpd.include`:

```
ExtendedLog         /var/log/proftpd/auth.log AUTH auth 
LogFormat           auth "%v [%h] %s"
```

Example of unsuccessfull login (530):

`/var/log/proftpd/auth.log`:

```
ProFTPD [12.89.47.3] 331
ProFTPD [12.89.47.3] 530
```

**What's the correct regexp for fail2ban ?** My configuration seems not to match the pattern:

`/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/proftpd.conf`:

```
failregex = ProFTPD(.)+\[<HOST>\] 530$
```

`<HOST>` seems to be a fail2ban variable, and `$` ends up a rule (if you want to set several rules inside the `failregex =` variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the following is working on Plesk 10.4.

proftpd.include:

```
ExtendedLog         /var/log/proftpd/auth.log AUTH auth
LogFormat           auth "%v %t \"%r\" [%h] %s"
```

/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/proftpd.conf:

```
failregex = \[<HOST>\]\s+530$
```